# How do I get button up even when out of focus with actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been working on creating a button using a MovieClip. I'm using the following events:

```
 this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,OnClick);
 this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,OnButtonRollOver);
 this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,OnButtonRollOut);
 this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,OnMouseDown);
 this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,OnMouseUp);
```

Everything works fine with the exception of when I click the button and [without releasing the mouse button] I drag the mouse out of the button's focus and then I release the mouse button the OnMouseUp event is not called.

How can I fix this?
Thanks,
Y_Y.

Comment: Do you need separate actions to occur on mouse_down and mouse_up? Can you sidestep the problem by using just one event or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `OnMouseDown` handler you can add the following to ensure you get the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` event you desire:

```
private function OnMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);
}

private function onStageMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);
    // handle mouse up here
}
```

Of course this means you'll have to do some extra work to make sure handlers are being added/removed appropriately. You might also want to cache a reference to the target button in your `OnMouseDown` handler in the event the scenario you describe occurs and you still need to know which button was pressed (assuming your handlers are outside the scope of the button itself).